# MatLab can't recognize Visual C++ 2010 redistirbutable, compiler error

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have reinstalled C++ redistributable, rebooted, searched online, read the help files, i don't know what to do.

Matlab Coder sais:

*Validation Report for: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 v10.0 | nmake (32-bit Windows): 
Toolchain is not installed.*

I've tried for an hour to follow various complex steps of toolchain setup and nothing is working, i don't even know what the problem is, if it's a registry key or something.

Please help me. mex: **Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)'.
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)' for C++ language compilation.**

Warning: File 'setup_mssdk71.bat' not found.

> In coder.make.ToolchainInfo/configureToolchain/configureProperty (line 2382)

The compiler aborts and tells me that *LCC is Matlab's default compiler, if i want to compile C i have to undo the C++ option.*

```
>> mex -setup c++ -v
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER12' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER12' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER12' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 '.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'ICPP_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Professional' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'VS90COMNTOOLS' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Professional'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Professional' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'VS100COMNTOOLS' ...Yes ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A' InstallationFolder ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Professional'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 11.0 ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 12.0 ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1' InstallationFolder ...Yes ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 10.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 10.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)'.
... Looking for compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)' ...
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1' InstallationFolder ...Yes ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 10.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VC7' 10.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)'.
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)' for C++ language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
     you will be required to update your code to utilize the
     new API. You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
```

Comment: Which Matlab version? Do you have the professional edition of visual c++? Is sp1 vor visual c++ installed?

Comment: It's version 2015a, I have c++ sdk for x86 win7 and c++ redistributable version 8,9,10,12 2010 and 2013. I will see for sp1 thankyou.

Comment: I don't have visual studio installed, i wish to have a C++ version of some code as reference to convert into C#, only the sdk and redist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it working.

After installing uninstalling a dozen times, i installed first dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe, and win SDK for version 4, and i rebooted and it worked... in the meantime i also installed composer XE compiler which worked too, i dont know if it overwrote some registry issues but it was fixed after installing those 3.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed visual c++ redistributable, this is not a compiler. You need visual c++ or one of the other supported compilers.

Check the documentation for your Matlab version for a complete list, Windows sdk 7.1 is probably the best choice.

Comment: Thanks, using mex -setup, matlab states that it has found sdk 7.1, and it lets me select it as a compiler but during compilation, v7.1 is located in program files/microsoft sdks/windows, when i installed it i had take uninstall and reinstall the redistributable 2010 and 2013 which came after v7.1. I have tried to get it to see C++ 2008 redistributable and it doesnt see it either.

Comment: i just tried to check v7.1 it said: Validation Report for: Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1 | nmake (32-bit Windows)

### Validating other build tools ...

Unable to locate build tool "Microsoft Visual C Compiler": cl

Unable to locate build tool "Microsoft Visual C Linker": link

Unable to locate build tool "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler": cl

Unable to locate build tool "Microsoft Visual C++ Linker": link

Unable to locate build tool "Microsoft Visual C/C++ Archiver": lib

Comment: i have to go back to an early post i saw about registering mssdk in environmental variables.

Comment: also have Warning: File 'setup_mssdk71.bat' not found. 
> In coder.make.ToolchainInfo/configureToolchain/configureProperty (line 2382)

Comment: You are writing again about visual c++ redistributable. That is not a compiler, Matlab can't use the Redistributable.

Comment: SDK requires .net framework 4. does it look like, having installed SDK 7.1 and .net framework elements a dozen times, i may have missed something? all these hours of troubleshooting this issue, you would be brilliant if you could actually identify the solution.  See here they make out as if you can use other microsoft products with for example, the nmake compiler from 4.0: http://fr.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/index.html?refresh=true

Comment: i didn't mark you down by the way. the original question has the mex setup verbose: Found installed compiler 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)'.